# Main menu Contact button does not scroll all the way down to anchor #contact

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the menu button "Kontaktujte nás!" (= "Contact us!") to scroll all the way down to anchor #contact, but it scrolls only to circa 80% of the section above the Contact.
Once the Contact section is fully loaded (user have already scrolled down), the button works fine.

https://www.solarnimise.cz/

Any idea what could be the problem please? Thank you very much!

Comment: In my pc its working fine!

Comment: @Aahad on the first try? You just open the link, click on "KONTAKTUJTE NÁS!" button in main menu and it scrolls all the way down to "Kontakt" section with form?

Comment: sometime its scrolling and sometimes its not you should upload your code!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out, it was caused by the `lozad` in img classes. Not sure about the details of the problem, but I simply got rid of it modifying for example:

```
    <img
    class='lozad img-responsive {{ cond (eq ( mod $index 4) 1)  "img-clip-right-backward" "img-clip-right-forward" }}'
    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwACAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAHAAIAAAIDjI9YADs="
    data-src="{{ .image.x | absURL }}"
    data-srcset="{{ .image.x | absURL }} 1x, {{ .image._2x | absURL }} 2x"
    alt="{{ .title }}"
    />
```

to:

```
    <img
    class='img-responsive {{ cond (eq ( mod $index 4) 1)  "img-clip-right-backward" "img-clip-right-forward" }}'
    src="{{ .image.x | absURL }}"
    srcset="{{ .image.x | absURL }} 1x, {{ .image._2x | absURL }} 2x"
    alt="{{ .title }}"
    />
```

and all good now!